# Testing method: Using 'Private Browsing' for testing sites without cache?

Tags: testing, caching, load-testing

I'm wondering if anyone switches to private browsing mode to test sites sans cache?
You know when you have to clear cache to make sure that what you are seing is fresh from the server, surely private browsing is a safe, and faster way to do this, instead of having to go to your settings each time and clearing.

Putting this out there to see how other people do it or if theres a catch to this way of testing that i may not be aware of.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I realize I'm late to the party, but I stumbled upon this question when searching for more information about "InPrivate Browsing" with IE8.

I felt I should add that, at least with IE8, browsing "InPrivate" does NOT prevent cache files from being written to disk. What it does do, however, is delete its cached files when the browser is closed.

So, if I understand your particular use, there appears to be no benefit to using InPrivate browsing with IE8 at all, unless you are closing your browser each time.

Alternatively, what's wrong with a forced refresh (`Ctrl+F5`)?

Similarly, a quick hotkey for deleting cache files is `Ctrl+Shift+Del` followed by `Enter` to confirm (faster than clicking). At least with my fingers on my keyboard, this is a very quick and easy one handed combination.

Comment: Funny I also picked up on this shortcut for chrome only yesterday. Maybe it came with the latest update?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, private browsing would work well for that in most situations.

The only 'catches' would be things like being behind a caching proxy or sites that use some of the new HTML 5 features which are not well handled in private mode at present ([more details](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/08/06/private_browsing_mode_failure/)).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think private browsing actually gives you an "empty" cache. It still uses your current cache, just doesn't save any new files to it. So if you ever visit the site without private browsing, then you're back to square one anyway...